# x-googl-acl isn't making uploaded files public

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Currently I have been trying to upload objects (videos) to my Google Storage Cloud. I have found out the reason (possibly) that I haven't been able to make them public is due to `ACL or IAM` permission. The way it's currently done is I get a signedUrl from the backend as

```
const getGoogleSignedUrl = async (root, args, context) => {
  const { filename } = args;
  const googleCloud = new Storage({
    keyFilename: ,
    projectId: 'something'
  });

  const options = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'write',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    contentType: 'video/quicktime',
    extensionHeaders: {'x-googl-acl': 'public-read'}
  };

  const bucketName = 'something';

  // Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
  const [url] = await googleCloud
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(filename)
    .getSignedUrl(options);

  return { url };
}
```

Once I have gotten temporary permission from the backend as a url I try to make a put request to uploaded the file as:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: blob,
  headers: {
    'x-googl-acl': 'public-read',
    'content-type': 'video/quicktime'
  }
}).then(res => console.log("thres is ", res)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Even though the file does get uploaded to google cloud storage. It is always showing public access as `Not public`. Any help would be helpful since I am starting to not understand how making an object public with google cloud works.

Within AWS (previously) it was easy to make an object public by adding `x-aws-acl` to a put request.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I have changed the code to reflex currently what it looks like. Also when I look at the object in Google Storage after it's been uploaded I see

`Public access` Not authorized

`Type` video/quicktime

`Size` 369.1 KB

`Created` Feb 11, 2021, 5:49:02 PM

`Last modified` Feb 11, 2021, 5:49:02 PM

`Hold status` None

`Retention` policy None

`Encryption type` Google-managed key

`Custom` time —

`Public URL` Not applicable

**Update 2**

As stated. The issue where I wasn't able to upload the file after trying to add the recommended header was because I wasn't providing the header correctly. I changed the header from `x-googl-acl` to `x-goog-acl` which has allowed me to upload it to the cloud.

New problem is now `Public access` is showing as `Not authorized`

**Update 3**

In order to try something new I followed the direction listed here `https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/`. Once I finished everything. The next steps I took was

1 - Upload a new video to the cloud. This will be done using the new json provided

```
  const googleCloud = new Storage({
    keyFilename: json_file_given),
    projectId: 'something'
  });
```

Once the file has been uploaded I noticed there was no changes in regards to it being public. Still has `Public access Not authorized`

2 - Once checking the status of the object uploaded I went on to follow similar approach on the bottom to make sure I am using the same account as the json object that uploaded the file.

`gcloud auth activate-service-account test@development-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=test_google_account.json`

3 - Once I noticed I am using the right person with the right permission I performed the next step of

`gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://example-bucket/example-object`

This is return actually resulted in a response of `No changes to gs://crit_bull_1/google5.mov`

Comment: For the upload to use the `x-goog-acl`, that header must be specified when creating the Signed URL. The client headers must match the headers specified when creating the Signed URL.

Comment: For Node.js, the config option is `extensionHeaders`. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getSignedUrl This answer has a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224835/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you very much for that link. That is amazing although after following that post. I noticed I am still getting the same response. I am updating my post with what I have changed. Please let me know if you see something I may have done wrong. Thank you again for that link and the help.

Comment: Your code update appears correct. What type of access control is setup for the bucket: Fine-grained or Uniform?

Comment: @JohnHanley I just realized I was doing `x-googl-acl` when it was suppose to be `x-goog-acl`. Now I am getting a `Public access Not authorized`. I thought ACL works differently then IAM when adding permission?

Comment: @JohnHanley I have not modified from what was given when i created the bucket. It says it is `Fine-grained` Thank you again for the help

Comment: I looked at your code several times and I did not see the misspelling. I wondered why you did not receive an error in your first code version as the headers did not match the signing request. Now I know why, the header was ignored because it was not recognized as a Google header.

Comment: Please do not edit your question "in-place" like you just did. Instead add a new section at the end. Otherwise comments and suggestions will not make sense to future readers and the process to solve your original problem will be lost.

Comment: @JohnHanley As you have recommended. I have modified the comment to how it was previously and made updated under. Sorry about making `in-place` changes. It does make sense though.

Comment: I do not remember what the solution is to that error. What is the exact error message? Can you change the ACL using `gsutil` and in the console (test both methods) using the same credentials. What roles does the service account used to create the signed URL have?

Comment: I apologize if I don't understand some parts. I'm not sure how to use `gsutil` in console. How would I go about to do that? as for the service account. I just checked and the role of the service account says `Owner`

Comment: I meant use `gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://example-bucket/example-object` from your computer and then use Google Cloud Console GUI in your browser. My goal is to see if you have a permission/rights problem. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded and was able to do the command recommended. Seems to be a permission problem since the error I am getting was `CommandException: Failed to set acl for gs://crit_bull_1/google4.mov. Please ensure you have OWNER-role access to this resource.` I am a little confused because when I was creating a service account it ask for an account name which becomes the ID. For example is I say yama12 it makes it yama12@bucket.iam.gserviceaccount.com but I noticed currently it is referencing my Google email address for logging in as authorized.

Comment: 1) Which IAM storage roles are assigned to the service account used to create the Signed URL? 2) You can add the service account email address as a legacy bucket owner. In the Google Cloud Console go to Cloud Storage -> "click on bucket name". Go to the "Permissions" tab. Add the service account email address and give it the "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner" role.

Comment: In summary you have three problems: 1) Misspelling of the header `x-goog-acl`. 2) Mismatch between the headers specified when creating the signed URL and the upload request. 3) Insufficient permissions to make a bucket object public.

Comment: I've resolved the first two. The last one I am still having a little bit of a problem. I followed your directions by going to `Permissions` then creating a new permission with the email given to me by the service account. Now `Members` include the name@bucket.iam.gserviceaccount.com as `Storage Legacy Bucket Owner` but I am unable to do public through the app. I can't use gsutil since it asked me to login with my gmail account and that makes it invalid since the email given by the service creator is different.

Comment: To setup the CLI with a service account, read my article: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/

Comment: What error do you get after setting up the bucket permissions for the service account? Double check that you set this up correctly.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've followed the direction and created a new one with `Storage Admin`. Once I run it in the terminal the response I get was `No changes to gs://bucket_name/google4.mov`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are reporting with the last comment. Was the object already public? Start over, upload an object, then use the CLI to make the object public using the "SAME" service account as the code that uploaded the object.

Comment: @JohnHanley I made an update on what I've done in regards to the current recommendation and what I am currently seeing as a response. Thank you again with the help.

Comment: As an alternative to debug this issue, once you get the signed URL have you tried to upload the video using curl?: `curl -X PUT -H 'x-googl-acl': 'public-read' -H 'content-type': 'video/quicktime' --upload-file my-file [signedURL]`